# Get sender of a message in Smalltalk

Tags: oop, smalltalk, squeak

Is there a practical way to get the sender of a message in Smalltalk **without manually passing self** as a Parameter?

To be more concrete: I want to add a class specific prefix to an ID that gets passed to my class, so if ClassA sends (on class side)

```
ClassB doSomethingWith: 'myId'.
```

ClassB should internally treat 'myId' as 'ClassB-myId' or something similar.

I have implemented this with an additional parameter which has to be self

```
ClassB doSomethingWith: 'myId' for: self.
```

but I would be very glad if there is a solution without this explicit send of self.

Comment: I don't understand what you want; ClassB knows its name so it can prepend it to the symbol…

Comment: ClassA shoudln't have to care that classB uses per-class namespaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the reflective facilities on the execution stack:

`thisContext sender receiver`

1. `thisContext` answers the current stack frame
2. `sender` answers the parent stack frame
3. `receiver` answers the receiver of the stack frame

This should work in Pharo, VisualWorks and GemStone. Other Smalltalk might use different method names.